# FileNotFound Exception with

Tags: java, 7zip

I have the following code;

```
String files="";
for (int i=0; i<filelist.size()-1;i++)
{
    files=files+filelist.get(i).getPath()+", ";
}
files=files+filelist.get(filelist.size()-1).getPath();
System.out.println(files);
Process zipping=new ProcessBuilder(
           "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe", "a", "-t7z", "C:/Users/Pc/dog/test", files).start();
OutputStream steam=zipping.getOutputStream();
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
FileInputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Pc/dog/test.7z"));
client.files.upload("/test.7z").

uploadAndFinish(in);
```

Which gives `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Pc\dog\test.7z` error.

In addition, though the archive file is created, it does not contain the given files, which are given as;

```
C:\Users\Pc\Documents\untitled3.png, C:\Users\Pc\Documents\untitled2.png
```

Comment: You appear to sometimes refer to "test.7z" and sometimes refer to "text.7z". My guess is that that's at least part of the issue... As for the missing files - are they in `files`?

Comment: That was part of the issue, but not the issue itself.

Comment: So *does* that file exist? You haven't given enough information about what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, the file is created with the ProcessBuilder.

Comment: I think `test.7z` is not available in this folder `C:/Users/Pc/dog/`. Have you checked it carefully? @YusufKayaKuzu

Comment: It is not supposed to be on the folder initially. It is supposed to be created by the Process, which creates it. I don't have a problem when it is created beforehand, but that's not my intention in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting the process, but you're trying to use the file before it's had much of a chance to get going.

I suspect you need to wait for it to finish:

```
zipping.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I can't still zip multiple files in one go, but this works.